# When should i use skydrive and when should i use azure for simple DataStorage?

Tags: c#, azure-storage, winrt-xaml, onedrive

I am doing windows store application,the app main goal is that,it is having the capability of storing,updating and retrieving,so i want to store this information in cloud,which is the better option for me skydrive or windows azure? and when i should go for azure and when for SkyDrive? i am new to c# and windows store apps,if anyone provides references,that would be grateful.

Comment: This is not an appropriate type of question to ask on stackoverflow, as is described in [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).

Comment: Sure? I think it is - because at the end there are clear guidelines by microsoft on what is allowed on skydrive for a windows shop app. See my answer.

Comment: @Servy : Can you please check the link which you suggested in your comment,i found some gorilla story there :)

Comment: @pashaplus That is exactly the link that I meant to post.  Perhaps you didn't get past the humorous title and actually read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which is the better option for me skydrive or windows azure?

None. This is different, not better.

SkyDrive is a USERS DOCUMENT SPACE. It is not for setting files (by definition and agreement). It is for stuff that the user HAS INTEREST IN MANIPULATING - documents, schedules etc.

Azure and a database you write are your application storage.

The question rarely comes up. Bascially you can ask "does the user want to open these files on another computer". If not - no reason to put them into the users space.

Check

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826545.aspx

the last paragraph (Guidelines for apps that interact with SkyDrive).